# Unsure why this LOOKAHEAD is needed in these contexts

Tags: parsing, javacc, regex-lookarounds, javaparser

Here is my token table:

```
TOKEN :
{
  < A : "A" >
| < B : "B" >
| < C : "C" >
}
```

I have this code that contains 2 choice conflicts.

```
void Start() : {} {
    < A> [ Bs() ] "-" < A>
}
void Bs() : {} {
    ( "-" < B> )+
}
```

In order to remove the choice conflicts warning, I need to add 2 LOOKAHEAD statements like so...

```
void Start() : {} {
    < A> [ LOOKAHEAD(2) Bs() ] "-" < A>
}
void Bs() : {} {
    ( LOOKAHEAD(1) "-" < B> )+
}
```

I understand why the first LOOKAHEAD(2) is needed but I have no idea why the second LOOKAHEAD(1) is needed. Can someone please explain?

Similarly for this example...

```
void Start() :{} {
    one()
    |
    two()
    |
    three()
    |
    four()
}
void one() : {} {
    [ <B> ] ( <A> )* <C>
}
void two() : {} {
    <B> <A> < A> <B>
}
void three() : {} {
    <B> <B> <A> [ <B> ] <A>
}
void four() : {} {
    <A> [ <B><C> ] two()
}
```

In order to remove the choice conflicts, I need to add LOOKAHEADS like so...

```
void Start() :{} {
    LOOKAHEAD(1) one()
    |
    LOOKAHEAD(1) two()
    |
    three()
    |
    four()
}
void one() : {} {
    [ <B> ] ( <A> )* <C>
}
void two() : {} {
    <B> <A> < A> <B>
}
void three() : {} {
    <B> <B> <A> [ <B> ] <A>
}
void four() : {} {
    <A> [ LOOKAHEAD(1) <B><C> ] two()
}
```

I have no idea why these LOOKAHEADS remove the warnings. Any help understanding would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For your first example, because of the way you defined `Start`, `Bs` can be followed by a "-" token.  Now say the input is `A - B - ...`. Should the `( "-" < B> )+` loop be executed once or twice?  It depend on the next item of input. If it's an A, once, if it's a B, at  least twice.  So the parser needs to look past the "-".

For your second example: JavaCC does not give warnings when you put in LOOKAHEAD specifications, even if the LOOKAHEAD specifications are not sufficient to deal with the problem.  In this case you could use

```
void Start() :{} {
    LOOKAHEAD([ <B> ] ( <A> )* <C>) one()
    |
    LOOKAHEAD(<B> <A>) two()
    |
    three()
    |
    four()
}
```